# Is it possible to merge several vertices at once?

Tags: mesh, blender-internal-render-engine, vertices

I wanted to ask if it is possible to merge several vertices at once? like not having to select the two single vertices that I want to merge everytime and then merging them manually but rather select a bunch of vertices at one?

what I have:
[image]

what I want:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make a selection including the vertices you want to merge, but not including other vertices which are close to one another that you don't want to merge, vertex menu <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> > 'Remove Doubles', adjust 'Merge Distance' in the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

While modelling you can use [transform snapping](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/snap.html#transform-snapping) to snap a vertex to the location of another vertex. Next to the snapping options is the auto-merge option. With this enabled vertices will merge as you snap them together.

[image: auto merge option]

When the snapping is disabled, you can hold <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> while moving to enable it temporarily, this means you can move as you want and when you want to merge a vertex with another, hold <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> to snap and it will also be merged, without holding <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> no merging will happen.

If you snap and merge by accident you can use <kbd>V</kbd> to [rip](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html#separating) the vertex apart, <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> will also fill in the hole made by the rip.